# Move quantity field to top of product options?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, quantity

I'm looking to move my quantity field to the top of my product options. I'd like to have it under the short description if possible. Just having a hard time locating where you change the layout for this stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The quantity box is located in the file `.../frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`.

As long as you keep the field in the form located in `.../frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` it should work. So either remove it from the `addtocart.phtml` or move the whole `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>` in the `view.phtml`.